# How to update limits.memory using command line in Openshift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, ose

I would like to update or change memory limit to 90Gi in this spec using command line.

spec:
hard:
limits.cpu: 12500m
limits.memory: 80Gi
pods: "10"
requests.cpu: 12500m
requests.memory: 80Gi

The current steps are oc edit quota compute-resources, manually change the limit and save.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following commands for your purpose.

For specific quota modification.

```
$ oc delete quota <name> && oc create quota <name> \
     --hard=cpu=12500m,memory=80Gi
```

For specific deploymentconfig which you can list using `oc get dc`.

```
$ oc set resources dc/<target deploymentconfig name> \
   --limits=cpu=12500m,memory=80Gi \
   --requests=cpu=12500m,memory=80Gi
```

Comment: Thanks @Daein-park for the reply, can you help with the exact command. I am new to OSE and unable to find the target deployment config name.

Comment: @Rajiv I check your question again, and I recognized it's about quota, not specific deploymentconfig. I updated above my answer for the quota.

Comment: The ResourceQuota "compute-resources" is invalid: spec.scopes: Invalid value: []core.ResourceQuotaScope(nil): field is immutable
[

Comment: As  far as I can see the message, in the Quota case, you should create Quota resource again after removing it.

Comment: If you can create Quota resource, you can also remove it either. Please reach out to your OCP administrator, because you may not have a permission enough to operate Quota resource.